# What do I do if a colleague has rebased after pushing?

Tags: git, rebase

I had checked out `somebranch`. A colleague has done some work and rebased it, now `origin/somebranch` is parallel to `somebranch`. I've done no work on the branch, but I am 14 commits behind, 3 commits ahead and with merge conflicts on two files. What do I do to not add a junk merge now?

Bonus question: what should I do if I had done some local work on the pre-overwrite branch?

### EDIT:

To clarify what I've done. I did

```sh
git fetch
git checkout somebranch
```

Some time later I clicked on the sync button in vscode which, as far as I know, does attempt

```
git pull origin somebranch
git push origin somebranch
```

The operation failed, there has been a merge initiated on two files.

The histories now look like (a longer version of) this:

```
* 8e1e0ed - (2 days ago) commit9 (origin/somebranch)
* c87977f - (9 days ago) commit8
* adfc49e - (3 weeks ago) commit2
* 7c8e72e - (3 weeks ago) commit1
* e158c80 - (8 days ago) commit7 (origin/master, master)
* 2357f78 - (8 days ago) commit6
| * 7b507a3 - (9 days ago) commit5 (HEAD -> somebranch)
| * 2a7af7b - (3 weeks ago) commit2
| * c424261 - (3 weeks ago) commit1
|/  
* 48098a0 - (3 weeks ago) commit0
```

I.e. `commit1` and `commit2` are different on my version of branch and origin. And `commit5` is replaced with other commits. What am I supposed to do now?

Comment: Rebase your own work on top? Generally you can just `git pull -r`.

Comment: What do you mean with "I am 14 commits behind, 3 commits ahead and..."?

Comment: You mean someone rebased the origin with their own local branch? That sounds a bit odd. Worse case rebase your local off of origin or delete your local and checkout again

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You cannot have "merge conficts" unless _you_ attempt a rebase or a merge or similar. But you have not described doing something like that. Trust me, merge conflicts do not appear by magic on your machine! Please go back and think carefully about _what you did_ and describe it, step by step. Never mind what "a colleague" did; all we care about is what happened on _this computer_. Thanks!

Comment: @SwissCodeMen I pulled `somebranch`. A colleague rebased `somebranch` on latest `master` and forcepushed it. Now my `somebranch` has 3 commits that are not the same commits as on `origin/somebranch` and the `origin/somebranch` has 14 commits that I don't.

Comment: Okay, well, this is a serious situation. The good news is that _you_ didn't force push. Here's a good article to show your colleague on what to do after screwing up in this way. https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/git-push---force-and-how-to-deal-with-it

Comment: @matt I edited the question as you suggested, and included a shortened version of current histories. Does that make it more clear?

Comment: The history gives a lot of detail, thanks! I’ve answered based on that graph, but my answer might need adapting depending on how close the actual history is to that abridged copy here. For example, my answer presumes there’s only one commit 5 that doesn’t exist on the origin's branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Keeping commit 5

Commit 1 and 2 already exist, so the only commit to rebase is commit 5, and HEAD is at the end of your branch with commit 5 so that doesn’t need specifying.

```
git rebase --onto origin/somebranch HEAD~
```

A new commit 5 will be created with a parent of commit 9.

### Not keeping commit 5

If you don’t want any of the commits on your branch, that’s a simpler situation. It’s just a case of resetting your local branch to the remote branch.

```
git reset --hard origin/somebranch
```

Comment: Thanks! There's one more detailed that I've failed convey — this `commit5` was a "wip" commit that was intentionally undone and redone by 8&9. I think it makes my case easier (i.e. I should somehow just "force pull" the branch from origin), but it also complicates the case if I would've added my own work on top of commit5...

Comment: @Džuris That’s very different but also simply solved, I’ve edited my answer. I don’t think it complicates matters if you had done work on top since you could do the first rebase command to replay your work on to the origin branch just like I was suggesting with commit 5